# How to remove element from list if element is present in list Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that I am trying to remove an element from each list if the element is present in the list.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get link and parse
page = requests.get('https://www.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&ft=4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print('List of filters\n')

# return 'Title's for each filter
titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'screener-combo-title'})
title_list = []
for t in titles:
    title_list.append(t.contents)

print(title_list)
```

Sample output:

```
[['Price/Free Cash Flow'], ['EPS growth', <br/>, 'this year'], ['EPS growth', <br/>, 'next year']]
```

Desired output:

```
[['Price/Free Cash Flow'], ['EPS growth', 'this year'], ['EPS growth', 'next year']]
```

The issue I have been running into is that my checks to see if the element is present aren't working. I have tried `if '<br/>' in whatever:` and `whatever.remove('<br/>')`. `NoneType is non callable`. I see that I am putting `<br/>` in as a string, but I also see it's not a string in the list. I have tried dropping `''` and that came back `unresolved reference`. I have tried checking if each list has multiple elements and if so to remove the 2nd element but that also came back `NoneType is non callable`.

Comment: See [`.strings` and `.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) which you might prefer over `.contents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case [`.strings` and `.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) should be preferred over `.contents`

So change

```
for t in titles:
    title_list.append(t.contents)
```

to

```
for t in titles:
    title_list.append(list(t.stripped_strings))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try by only appending objet with isinstance of string:

```
for t in titles:
    title_sublist=[] 
    for content in t.contents:
        if isinstance(content, str) :
            title_sublist.append(content)
    title_list.append(title_sublist)
```

Comment: The result is an empty list. `contents` becomes an `unresolved reference`.

Answer (score 2):

Elements of your lists aren't strings. They are instances of bs4.element. class. You have to compare it like this:

```py
title_list = []
for t in titles:
    title_list.append([])
    for c in t.contents:
        if c.string != None:
            title_list[-1].append(c) # or c.string if you need only names
```

.string of `</br>` is <s>empty</s> `None` and for the others it is what you see in output.

Comment: I am getting back the same list, keeping up to date with the edits.